# How to install Gnome2 on Xubuntu?

Tags: 11.04, xubuntu, gnome2

How to install Gnome2 on xubuntu 11.04 ?

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to use gnome in xubuntu is to just install Ubuntu in the first place, but if you must installing gnome via apt-get should work, but it might give you a ton of extra packages.

```
sudo apt-get install gnome
```

or better yet the ubuntu desktop

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Answer (score 2):

You can install either [Gnome](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gnome) with everything.

Or [Gnome Core](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gnome-core) which is minimal.

Answer (score 0):

I installed xubuntu 10.04 and then gnome-core on my laptop because I prefer gnome.  I like it a lot and it is a lean system, gnome tends to run using only around 130 MB of RAM.  The most RAM I have used so far that I can remember is around 250MB.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](http://askubuntu.com/privileges/comment).